# Yahoo Finance YQL Query limit columns being returned

Tags: json, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

The yahoo finance api YQL query is great for getting stock data, but it returns so many things, most of which I am not interested in.

A basic query like,

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = 'GOOG'
```

returns every parameter available, some of which are empty.

All that I want is 'symbol', 'name', 'volume', and 'ask'.
So how do I restrict the results to just this data?

I've tried:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = 'GOOG' and columns = 'Symbol,Name,Volume,Ask'
```

But the results are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select Symbol,Name,Volume,Ask from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = 'GOOG'
```

Rest call: http://tinyurl.com/kmwn5ke

**EDIT**
YQL documentation for syntax of SELECT in YQL [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select_syntax.html).